# How to add plus minus symbol to a basic accordion using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I'm using basic jQuery accordion written by Luca Filosofi from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404657/jquery-accordion-definition-list-with-multiple-description-items). Here is my version:

```
$('.product-details .post-body dl dt').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('dl').children('dd:visible').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).nextUntil('dt').filter(':not(:visible)').slideDown('fast');
});
```

The script works perfectly. However, I don't know how to have plus and minus text (`+`, `-`) attached before the **Title** (e.g: + Title) based if the content is shown or not.

I have the following permanent markup and it must stay as is. Must not add more class or html, except via jQuery:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd>Description 01</dd>
    <dd>Description 02</dd>

    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd>Description 01</dd>
    <dd>Description 02</dd>
    <dd>Description 03</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: What is meaning of *content is shown or not.*?

Comment: I use multiple descriptions to define a single term, treating <dt> as trigger button and all <dd> in the same group as content. Clicking single <dt> will expand all its content and automatically collapse other group content. Just like vertical tabs

Answer (score 1):

You could toggle the icons when they click like this:

```
$('.product-details .post-body dl dt').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('dl').children('dd:visible').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).nextUntil('dt').filter(':not(:visible)').slideDown('fast');
    $(this).closest('i').toggleClass("icon-circle-plus icon-circle-minus");
});
```

Comment: I made a slight modification, changed the 'i' to 'dt'. — But it triggers an active class as toggle, not as accordion. It only removes the active class when the same "dt" is clicked.

Comment: They find the element thath has the plus symbol, turn it in to a minus, and change the current clicked one to a plus. 

`$('.product-details .post-body dl dt').on('click', function (e) {    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('dl').children('dd:visible').slideUp('fast'); $(this).nextUntil('dt').filter(':not(:visible)').slideDown('fast'); 
$('.product-details .post-body').find('.icon-circle-plus').attr('class', 'icon-circle-minus'); 
$(this).closest('dt').attr('class', 'icon-circle-plus'); });`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to get last character of `dt` text using [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). If last character is `+` change it to `-` and if it is `-` change to `+`.

```js
$('dl dd').slideUp('fast');
$('dl dt').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().children('dd:visible').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).nextUntil('dt').not(':visible').slideDown('fast');
    $(this).text(function(i, text){
        return (text.slice(-1) == "-") ? (text.slice(0, -1) + " +") : (text.slice(0, -1) + " -");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
    <dt>Title +</dt>
    <dd>Description 01</dd>
    <dd>Description 02</dd>
    <dt>Title +</dt>
    <dd>Description 01</dd>
    <dd>Description 02</dd>
    <dd>Description 03</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, we have hundreds of article published using the given markup, and more to come, so customising the html for every single post really needs lots of work and not a good step for future publication. We better stick with default HTML without adding extra line of symbol or html, except via jQuery.

Comment: @Biyan There is no problem. You can do this using jquery like [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/66y6udrb/)

Comment: How do I move the "+/-" before the Title?

Comment: I checked the demo but it doesn't seem to work properly. e.g. if I click the first group, and without closing it clicking another group, the +/- symbol on the first group doesn't change.

Comment: also the logic is broken when doing click and switch multiple times.